# How can I get latitude, longitude of a location programmatically or using a api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How can I get latitude from a city name like Florida how can I get the latitude and longitude from sending a JSON request to a Google map API.

Is there any way to do this?

I need a solution in JavaScript or jQuery through JSON.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how i can get latitude , longitude of a location programmatically or using a api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616582/how-i-can-get-latitude-longitude-of-a-location-programmatically-or-using-a-api)

Comment: sorry but not help me a lot. i am doing it by simply through json. i am not forced anyone to help me. if anyone know that tell me about them.

Comment: You should edit your original question if it wasn't precise enough.

Comment: It doesn't help that you have **never** accepted an answer either...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not sure what you mean when you say send json but you can do it with this function:

```
function getLatLong(address){
      var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;

      geo.geocode({'address':address},function(results, status){
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                return results[0].geometry.location;
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }

       });

  }
```

that will return an object which you can reference with .lat() and .lng() to get the latitude and longitude.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  You can't return anything from an asynchronous callback.   You need to _use_ the result in the callback function.

Comment: Refer here for help: https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Answer (score 11):

You can use :

```
var address = "New Delhi";
$.ajax({
  url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+address+"&sensor=false",
  type: "POST",
  success: function(res){
     console.log(res.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
     console.log(res.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
  }
});
```

**Sample Response:**

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Address",
               "short_name" : "Address",
               "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Madrid",
               "short_name" : "Madrid",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Madrid",
               "short_name" : "M",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Community of Madrid",
               "short_name" : "Community of Madrid",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Spain",
               "short_name" : "ES",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "28039",
               "short_name" : "28039",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Address, 28039 Madrid, Madrid, Spain",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.447337,
               "lng" : -3.7070179
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.44868598029151,
                  "lng" : -3.705668919708498
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.44598801970851,
                  "lng" : -3.708366880291502
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJAcX0u1YoQg0R6ZlFdkOQgIA",
         "types" : [ "hospital", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "ＡＤＤＲＥＳＳ",
               "short_name" : "ＡＤＤＲＥＳＳ",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "19",
               "short_name" : "19",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_4", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "7",
               "short_name" : "7",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_3", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "2 Chome",
               "short_name" : "2 Chome",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_2", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Nakaimaizumi",
               "short_name" : "Nakaimaizumi",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Utsunomiya-shi",
               "short_name" : "Utsunomiya-shi",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Tochigi-ken",
               "short_name" : "Tochigi-ken",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Japan",
               "short_name" : "JP",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "321-0968",
               "short_name" : "321-0968",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Japan, 〒321-0968 Tochigi-ken, Utsunomiya-shi, Nakaimaizumi, 2 Chome−7−19 ＡＤＤＲＥＳＳ",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.5678955,
                  "lng" : 139.9034399
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 36.5675808,
                  "lng" : 139.9032638
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 36.5677206,
               "lng" : 139.9033588
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.5690871302915,
                  "lng" : 139.9047008302915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 36.5663891697085,
                  "lng" : 139.9020028697085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ4zq2MgxnH2ARrK-H9cHhAjE",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Address:",
               "short_name" : "Address:",
               "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pineville",
               "short_name" : "Pineville",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "1, Charlotte",
               "short_name" : "1, Charlotte",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mecklenburg County",
               "short_name" : "Mecklenburg County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "North Carolina",
               "short_name" : "NC",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "28134",
               "short_name" : "28134",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Address:, Pineville, NC 28134, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 35.04203100000001,
               "lng" : -80.863066
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.04337998029151,
                  "lng" : -80.86171701970851
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 35.04068201970851,
                  "lng" : -80.86441498029151
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ4dWtti2DVogRigDBRFUTccg",
         "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Address",
               "short_name" : "Address",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "AGB Colony Kacha Bazar Road",
               "short_name" : "AGB Colony Kacha Bazar Rd",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "AGB Colony",
               "short_name" : "AGB Colony",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Motijheel",
               "short_name" : "Motijheel",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Dhaka",
               "short_name" : "Dhaka",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Dhaka",
               "short_name" : "Dhaka",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Dhaka Division",
               "short_name" : "Dhaka Division",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bangladesh",
               "short_name" : "BD",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Address, AGB Colony Kacha Bazar Road, Dhaka, Bangladesh",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 23.7329981,
                  "lng" : 90.4223152
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 23.7326888,
                  "lng" : 90.4219839
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 23.7328435,
               "lng" : 90.4221496
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 23.7341924302915,
                  "lng" : 90.42349853029151
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 23.73149446970849,
                  "lng" : 90.42080056970849
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ4RhdqkS4VTcR9QELu9rNaAQ",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Address",
               "short_name" : "Address",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "3",
               "short_name" : "3",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Sweet Fern Lane",
               "short_name" : "Sweet Fern Ln",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Coventry",
               "short_name" : "Coventry",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kent County",
               "short_name" : "Kent County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Rhode Island",
               "short_name" : "RI",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "02816",
               "short_name" : "02816",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Address, 3 Sweet Fern Lane, Coventry, RI 02816, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 41.6763577,
               "lng" : -71.53721809999999
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 41.6777066802915,
                  "lng" : -71.53586911970849
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 41.6750087197085,
                  "lng" : -71.5385670802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ9cdx-89K5IkR24VLhLim8is",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Address",
               "short_name" : "Address",
               "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Chandolli Talli",
               "short_name" : "Chandolli Talli",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Nayapanchayat Chetra Dumaila { Bironkhal }",
               "short_name" : "Nayapanchayat Chetra Dumaila { Bironkhal }",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Patti Khatli",
               "short_name" : "Patti Khatli",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Chandolli Talli",
               "short_name" : "Chandolli Talli",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pauri Garhwal",
               "short_name" : "Pauri Garhwal",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Uttarakhand",
               "short_name" : "UK",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "246177",
               "short_name" : "246177",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Address, Chandolli Talli, Nayapanchayat Chetra Dumaila { Bironkhal }, Patti Khatli, Chandolli Talli, Uttarakhand 246177, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 29.839023,
               "lng" : 78.9964554
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 29.8403719802915,
                  "lng" : 78.99780438029151
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 29.8376740197085,
                  "lng" : 78.99510641970849
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJH609gR-NCTkR6XqpwaxHEJU",
         "types" : [ "place_of_worship", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "The Address",
               "short_name" : "The Address",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Hope Island",
               "short_name" : "Hope Island",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Queensland",
               "short_name" : "QLD",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Australia",
               "short_name" : "AU",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "4212",
               "short_name" : "4212",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "The Address, Hope Island QLD 4212, Australia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -27.8585983,
                  "lng" : 153.3562717
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -27.8603566,
                  "lng" : 153.3527792
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -27.8599467,
               "lng" : 153.3547341
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -27.8581284697085,
                  "lng" : 153.3562717
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -27.8608264302915,
                  "lng" : 153.3527792
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJIZJj8TcSkWsROGKFb_QL2bs",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "ａｄｄｒｅｓｓ",
               "short_name" : "ａｄｄｒｅｓｓ",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "7",
               "short_name" : "7",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_3", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Shōdokorochō",
               "short_name" : "Shōdokorochō",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Takatsuki-shi",
               "short_name" : "Takatsuki-shi",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Ōsaka-fu",
               "short_name" : "Ōsaka-fu",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Japan",
               "short_name" : "JP",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "569-0064",
               "short_name" : "569-0064",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Japan, 〒569-0064 Ōsaka-fu, Takatsuki-shi, Shōdokorochō, 7 ａｄｄｒｅｓｓ",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.8398552,
                  "lng" : 135.6145781
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 34.8398113,
                  "lng" : 135.6145126
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 34.8398268,
               "lng" : 135.6145553
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.84118223029149,
                  "lng" : 135.6158943302915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 34.8384842697085,
                  "lng" : 135.6131963697085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJkQ3tc0wdAWARodHx1Sz3pI4",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Address",
               "short_name" : "Address",
               "types" : []
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "28",
               "short_name" : "28",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Tanza - Trece Martires Road",
               "short_name" : "Tanza - Trece Martires Rd",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Trece Martires City",
               "short_name" : "Trece Martires City",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Cavite",
               "short_name" : "Cavite",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Calabarzon",
               "short_name" : "Calabarzon",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Philippines",
               "short_name" : "PH",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Address, 28 Tanza - Trece Martires Road, Trece Martires City, Cavite, Philippines",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 14.2919207,
                  "lng" : 120.8680844
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 14.2915517,
                  "lng" : 120.8676444
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 14.2917362,
               "lng" : 120.8678644
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 14.2930851802915,
                  "lng" : 120.8692133802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 14.2903872197085,
                  "lng" : 120.8665154197085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJYUlfGnSAvTMRc34heYWlFw0",
         "types" : []
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "ＡＤＤＲＥＳＳ",
               "short_name" : "ＡＤＤＲＥＳＳ",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "4",
               "short_name" : "4",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_3", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "2 Chome",
               "short_name" : "2 Chome",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_2", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Minamimachi",
               "short_name" : "Minamimachi",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mito-shi",
               "short_name" : "Mito-shi",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Ibaraki-ken",
               "short_name" : "Ibaraki-ken",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Japan",
               "short_name" : "JP",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "310-0021",
               "short_name" : "310-0021",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Japan, 〒310-0021 Ibaraki-ken, Mito-shi, Minamimachi, 2 Chome−4 ＡＤＤＲＥＳＳ",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.3752077,
                  "lng" : 140.471904
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 36.3751499,
                  "lng" : 140.4718129
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 36.3751785,
               "lng" : 140.4718554
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.3765277802915,
                  "lng" : 140.4732074302915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 36.3738298197085,
                  "lng" : 140.4705094697085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJjdzYU1MkImAR2HGAxMHMgPA",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "ＡＤＤＲＥＳＳ",
               "short_name" : "ＡＤＤＲＥＳＳ",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "12",
               "short_name" : "12",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_3", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "5 Chome",
               "short_name" : "5 Chome",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_2", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kokuryōchō",
               "short_name" : "Kokuryōchō",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Chōfu-shi",
               "short_name" : "Chōfu-shi",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Tōkyō-to",
               "short_name" : "Tōkyō-to",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Japan",
               "short_name" : "JP",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "182-0022",
               "short_name" : "182-0022",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Japan, 〒182-0022 Tōkyō-to, Chōfu-shi, Kokuryōchō, 5 Chome−12 ＡＤＤＲＥＳＳ",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.6490935,
                  "lng" : 139.5517727
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 35.6489615,
                  "lng" : 139.5515341
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 35.6490117,
               "lng" : 139.5516496
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.6503764802915,
                  "lng" : 139.5530023802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 35.6476785197085,
                  "lng" : 139.5503044197085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJcxR2uEPwGGAR42ysbaayK_0",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**Demo** : http://jsbin.com/riyakobero/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @Brett Pennings : Pls dont do unwanted edits that distort the answer. Try loading http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+address+"&sensor=false in a browser and see for yourself whether the lat and lng are variables.

Comment: @GlenThomas: Please validate your edits before distorting the answer. Ive added the demo for reference. Also check the returned object.