# Get latitude and longitude from a google map

Tags: google-maps

I would like my user to be able to select a place on a map and return me the lat and lon which can be uploaded to a database. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: php and html? is probably my best but im not great at them

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps V3 - populate text field with marker data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533303/google-maps-v3-populate-text-field-with-marker-data)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how i can get latitude , longitude of a location programmatically or using a api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616582/how-i-can-get-latitude-longitude-of-a-location-programmatically-or-using-a-api)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are dealing with Google Maps API (based on your question's tag), I guess taking taking advantage of the in-built API capabilities in JavaScript might help. You can go over to [this place](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp) to get started learning JavaScript, you will,then read [the API here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html), and finally will be able to post a form using JavaScript whose values have been auto-set by the JavaScript with the latitude and longitude of the point the user clicked on the map.

Here is a bit of what you might have to do, but you might need to learn some JavaScript to extend it or use it effectively:

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);

GEvent.addListener(map,"click", function(overlay, latlng) {     
  if (latlng) { 
    alert("Latitude : " + latlng.lat() + " , Longitude: " + latlng.lng() );
  }
});
```

So, assuming you create a simple html page with a form to hold the latitude and longitude like this:

```
<form action="some_server_side_script_or_path" method="POST" id="map_form">
 <!-- display the map -->
 <div id="map_canvas"></div>
 <label for="mlatitude">Male</label>
  <input type="text" name="mlatitude" id="mlatitude" readonly="readonly"/>
  <br />
<label for="mlongitude">Male</label>
  <input type="text" name="mlongitude" id="mlongitude" readonly="readonly"/>
  <br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Location" />
</form>
```

Then, by modfying our clik-handler like this, we can auto-set the latitude and longitude on the form, and then have the user simply click submit to post the values to the server.

```
GEvent.addListener(map,"click", function(overlay, latlng) {     
  if (latlng) { 
    var lat = document.getElementById("mlatitude");
    var lng = document.getElementById("mlongitude");
    lat.value = latlng.lat();
    lng.value = latlng.lng();
    //at this point, you can even use Javascript to auto-submit the form using
    //document.forms["map_form"].submit();
  }
});
```