# Get latitude and longitude of a certain point by a click in Google Maps HTML

Tags: javascript, html, maps

I want to know if there is any way that when I click in a map that I created in Google Map in my HTML with the Google Maps API I can get the "Latitude" and "Longitude" of that point and use those values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get latitude and longitude from a google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770383/get-latitude-and-longitude-from-a-google-map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example to attach an event handler on the click event to return the lat, lon...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ){
  alert( "Latitude: "+event.latLng.lat()+" "+", longitude: "+event.latLng.lng() ); 
});
```